# Is there a database that classifies NPM library vulnerabilities as exploitable vs. benign in the browser?

Tags: cve, node.js, npm

I maintain several Angular apps, which contain thousands of dependencies on NPM packages. GitHub's Dependabot notifies me of new known vulnerabilities every week (from the CVE database).

For example, Dependabot tells me that moment.js has [High Severity CVE 2022-24785](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/cve-2022-24785). If you look at the definition of that CVE, you will see it's only insecure when run on node.js. There is no security issue with running this version of moment.js in a browser, even if that browser happens to be running server-side, as in a WebDriver test.

It seems that many, but not all, of the JavaScript CVEs fall into this category: nothing to worry about if you code only runs in a browser. But of course, this creates a dangerous "boy who cried wolf" effect, since some CVEs really are relevant to the safety of code that runs in the browser.

Is there a database that classifies JavaScript library CVEs as dangerous vs. benign when run in a browser vs. on node.js? I have tried all sorts of different search keywords and I haven't been able to turn up a web page that even acknowledges this issue, let alone any pointers to a database of such information.

Comment: `NPM audit` should tell you about known problems, can you filter that info into a form more useful for you? Anecdotally, I would suggest that if you're pulling in so much code you can't keep up, maybe you should reconsider how much effort outsourcing is really saving you.

Comment: @dandavis `npm audit` is an improvement over Dependabot in that it displays the CVE description inline, so I don't have to search for each CVE by hand. However, it's the same issue in the end: the CVE's one-line description may or may not mention if the vulnerability is a server-side or browser-side issue. Even if it does, the information is not structured in a way that it can be filtered reliably. As for ditching open source frameworks and writing everything from scratch, I'm afraid that would create more problems than it would solve.

Comment: I think the answer is more likely no, but... in your example, it is not always clear, what is a "server". What if the app is build by a jenkins on every git push, and then it is tested by selenium, on a server?

Comment: @peterh Thanks, good point. I will edit the question to make it clear that I'm looking for a way to filter out issues where "this is a problem only when run on node.js." This is the case with the example CVE I linked to. There would be no issue running the affected version of moment.js under Selenium/WebDriver on a server.